# IIS Default Page

Tags: iis

I have Set default page in IIS by setting in web.config as

```
defaultDocument
  files
      clear
       add value="BeforeLoginPage.Html" 
       add value="Some_Page.Html" 

 files
 defaultDocument
```

in priority order.

But when i try to run the website, it goes to the default and url and i get 302 error and it automatically gets redirected to Login Page. But i want "BeforeLoginPage.Html" to be displayed when i run the application .. How can i Do that?''' ignore the missing tags

Comment: Next time please learn carefully how to format things in the Stack Overflow way. To learn where the unwanted redirection comes from, use FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: please make sure that you do not have any URL rewrite rule at the server level or site level. and when you use the iis default document make sure you removed all the unwanted default documents. when you use a custom default document it shows 304 or 200, not 302. 304: Not modified. The client requests a document that is already in its cache and the document has not been modified since it was cached. The client uses the cached copy of the document, instead of downloading it from the server.302 - Object moved.

Comment: Is your issue solved?